# Does anyone know what kind of Harmonica I would need to play this song(Link in the description)?

Tags: harmonica

I've heard that to play this, I would need a diatonic B flat harmonica but I don't really know. Please help!

Answer (score 1):

is played on a Bb diatonic (SP20), with tabs.  But it does use a bunch of bends (3' 3'' 4' 6'').  Of course if playing along you could use any key of harmonica; it would just sound higher or lower with the same tab.

A chromatic lets you play the accidentals without bending.

I've learned from other questions that tremolo harmonica is popular in Asia for its ability to handle melodies, but I don't have any experience with that kind.

Looks like you asked the same thing on http://seldane.proboards.com/thread/6009/harmonica-used-sora-kiseki and got some good answers.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need a chromatic harmonica, as there's a Bb and a B natural to be played. A diatonic in Eb or Bb would give the Bb, but not the B. The tune is moving in and out of C minor.

Comment: Oh ok, I think I understand, but do you think you could provide me an example of one because my birthday is coming up, and I really want to get a harmonica for myself.

Comment: Google 'chromatic harmonica' and you'll be astounded at the response.

Comment: It sounds like the recording in question could have bending in it instead of being played on a chromatic. Either that or the intonation is slightly off (whether the fault of the reed or the player).

Comment: @ToddWilcox - just listened again, and it's close to B rather than C ! I think it's easier to play the 'odd' notes using a chromatic, than to accurately (?) play an already bent note. The instrument doesn't sound too in tune with itself anyway. Similar to a pre-bend on guitar - you don't *know* if the note coming out is spot on, till you play it - then it's a bit late!